# Excel VBA sort crashes Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, office365

I have an excel spreadsheet with a lot of VBA behind it. It all runs fine on a PC. I'm now testing it on a Mac with Office 365 for Mac installed. The mac is running Big Sur, v11.3.

All of the more complicated code works just fine, but a simple sort function causes excel to crash. It doesn't throw a VBA error - it just flat out shuts down excel. Even if I use `On Error GoTo Something` so I can e.g. generate an error messsagebox, it won't even do that - as soon as it encounters this line of code, excel is gone.

The line of code that causes the crash is:

`rngAllData.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlDescending`

`rngAllData` is a valid range, and if I change the line of code to simply `rngAllData.Select` it selects the range I'm expecting to sort, no problems. It just doesn't seem to like the Sort function.

I have created a new excel document, added some random numbers into column A, and created a button that calls `Range("A1:A8").Sort key1:=Range("A1")` and the results are the same - instant crash. So the problem is clearly with the `Range.Sort`

How do I go about troubleshooting, given I don't get any error messages?
How can I modify the code so that it works on both PC and mac?

The full sub is copied below, the variables are declared elsewhere, and again, this works fine on a PC so it shouldn't be anything like a non-declared variable issue.

```
Sub SortData()
'This sub is called to sort table data
On Error GoTo errHandler

'Determine column number of clicked button
colNum = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column

'If the selected sort column is different to the last sorted column, reset the sort order back to default
If colNum <> lastSortCol Then sortOrder = False
lastSortCol = colNum

'Determine range of data
Set rngAllData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2)
Set rngAllData = rngAllData.Resize(rngAllData.Rows.Count - 2, rngAllData.Columns.Count - 1)

'Sort data
If sortOrder Then rngAllData.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlDescending
If Not sortOrder Then rngAllData.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlAscending
sortOrder = Not (sortOrder)
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox "Error in SortData.", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Mac on Excel is pretty much of a poor relation to the Windows version.  Ron de Bruin at macexcel.com has some useful info.  The only thing that stands out as a bit odd in your code is the Application.Caller and I don't know if the Mac version would handle that gracefully.  Can you reduce your code to just a sort call and see if that works?

Comment: You should qualify your sort-column. If the sheet is not the active sheet, `key1:=Cells(3, colNum)` will fail as unqualified `Cells` refers to the activesheet. Usually you should get a runtime error, but maybe behaviour on a Mac is different.

Comment: @SeniorMomentum, the Application.Caller function works OK - the intention of that section is to identify which column the clicked button is in, so I can call the same "sort" sub from multiple buttons and have them sort according to the column they're in. It correctly returns the column number. I have reduced the code to a simple `Range("A3:R46").Sort key1:=Cells(3,2), order1:=xlascending` and the results are the same - instant crash.

Comment: @FunThomas I will qualify the sheet as a matter of best practice, although that's not the cause of the problem - all of the buttons that call this sub are on one sheet, so it will always be the active sheet when this sub is called.

Comment: @FunThomas I'll have to eat my own words there to some extent. Qualifying the sheet was part of the solution, but it seems there is a bigger problem with sorting named ranges. I will post an update below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that excel for mac doesn't like to sort range objects.

My data table can vary in size, so to find the range of data to sort, I use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. Then I need to discount the three header rows, and the last column (which has some controls that should *not* be sorted), so I use `Range.Offset` and `Range.Resize`. Rather than have a huge preamble to my `Range.Sort` and make the line stretch off the side of the page, I figured I'd just create a range object to refer to:

```
'Determine range of data
Set rngAllData = Sheets("Job List").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2)
Set rngAllData = rngAllData.Resize(rngAllData.Rows.Count - 2, rngAllData.Columns.Count - 1)

'Sort data
If sortOrder Then rngAllData.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlDescending
If Not sortOrder Then rngAllData.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlAscending
sortOrder = Not (sortOrder)
```

The undesired behaviour appears as soon as I try a `Range.Sort` operation on any range object.

If, instead, I do it longhand:

```
'Determine range of data
Set rngAllData = Sheets("Job List").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2)

'Sort data
If sortOrder Then Sheets("Job List").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(rngAllData.Rows.Count - 2, rngAllData.Columns.Count - 1)
.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlDescending
If Not sortOrder Then Sheets("Job List").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(rngAllData.Rows.Count - 2, rngAllData.Columns.Count - 1)
.Sort key1:=Cells(3, colNum), order1:=xlAscending
sortOrder = Not (sortOrder)
```

...then it looks horrible, but it works.

I'm guessing that this is a bug in excel for Mac, rather than something I'm inherently doing wrong, but I will post another thread now that I have a more specifically identified issue, and see if I can find a way to tidy it up.

[Follow up post is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378394/range-sort-on-excel-for-mac-crashes-when-using-range-object)