# Excel for Mac crashes when using Range.Sort on range object

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sorting

I have an excel spreadsheet with 8 random numbers in cells A1 through A8. I then have two buttons, each running a VBA sub:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8").Sort key1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim oRange as Range
Set oRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
oRange.Sort key1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

When I click Button 1, the numbers in the cells are sorted in ascending order, as you'd expect.
When I click Button 2, excel immediately crashes and closes with no warning or error message.

In theory they should work the same, as far as I can tell. The second button is defining exactly the same range to be sorted as the first, it's just defining it ahead of time instead of at sort time. If I change `.Sort` to `.Select` they both select the same range, so it is not an issue with how I'm defining my range, just with sorting it.

This only happens on excel for mac; on a PC this works fine.

The mac is an Apple silicon MacBook Air running Big Sur v11.3. Excel for mac is version 16.48 (both are the latest versions at the time of writing).

Is this a problem that I can solve somehow (other than by explicitly defining my ranges at the time of sorting), or is this a Microsoft bug beyond my reach?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`? (in all places)

Comment: @braX no, exactly the same results

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67329197).  Can you explain why you think it's not?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'd prefer that you close the other one if you want to close one. This one has identified the specific issue at hand (i.e. using `Range.Sort` on a range object, as opposed to using `Range.Sort` at all), and simplifies the issue down to it's most basic format, to enable the issue to be more clearly identified, demonstrated and replicated.

Comment: @ASForrest good point (and done).  FWIW, you could have edited your last Q down to this though.